# Count the characters individually in a string using c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have a string as follows:

```
string str = "ssmmmjjkkkkrrr"
```

Using C#, I need to display the count of each individual character as follows:

```
 s = 2
 m = 3
 j = 2
 k = 4
 r = 3
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21):

The simplest way would be to use LINQ:

```
var counted = text.GroupBy(c => c)
                  .Select(g => new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() });

foreach (var result in counted)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", result.Key, result.Count);
}
```

Or even more briefly:

```
foreach (var group in text.GroupBy(c => c))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", group.Key, result.Count());
}
```

Comment: I'd vote this up but Jon doesn't need the rep! I'd done a LINQ solution too, but this one's better. Natch.

Comment: Why doesn't `GroupBy` appear in my Intellisense??

Comment: @ElRonnoco: Cause you have to add `using System.Linq`

Comment: @Nikhil I've got `using System.Linq;` Strange but if I type `text.GroupBy(` I then get Intellisense telling me the various calling signatures....

Comment: @JonSkeet missing last paranthetical on first line.

Answer (score 5):

```
string str = "ssmmmjjkkkkrrr";
var counts = str.GroupBy(c => c).Select(g => new { Char = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });

foreach(var c in counts)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", c.Char, c.Count);
}
```

Comment: Hi thomas, I don't have any idea on LINQ and also Lamda expressions. So Could you please send me in another way to understand this one.

Answer (score 5):

Since everyone has put linq solutions, I'll offer a simple code way to achieve the same result (probably much faster too)

```
 string str = "ssmmmjjkkkkrrr";
  Dictionary<char, int> counts = new Dictionary<char, int>();

  for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
       if (counts.ContainsKey(str[i]))
         counts[str[i]]++;
       else
         counts.Add(str[i], 1);

  foreach (var count in counts)
       Debug.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", count.Key, count.Value.ToString());
```

**EDIT**
In response to the performance comment below I'll try to make this a little faster, this is dirty code but it runs pretty quickly.

The dictionary method will suffer from the way dictionaries allocate storage, each time you add an item that crosses the allocated storage threshold it doubles the storage available (allocate new array with the new size and copy over all elements), that takes some time! This solution gets around that.

```
// we know how many values can be in char.
int[] values = new int[char.MaxValue];

// do the counts.
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    values[text[i]]++;

// Display the results.
for (char i = char.MinValue; i < char.MaxValue; i++)
    if (values[i] > 0)
       Debug.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", i, values[i]);
```

Comment: @El Ronnoco; In the example you've provided how come you start the timer with DateTime.Today and use DateTime.Now to work out the elapsed time?

Comment: Thank you Andy for giving the solution.

Comment: You're welcome, if it really is homework then maybe go for the dictionary version first, the speedy version wastes a few bytes of memory to achieve it's speed ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
mystring.GroupBy(ch => ch)
        .Select(a => new { ch = a.Key, count = a.Count() })
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", x.ch, x.count));
```

Comment: Hi Nikhil, I don't have any idea on LINQ and also Lamda expressions, so could you please send me in another way. Thank you

Comment: @Subbu you have tagged it as C# 3,4 do you want one that works for 2.0 ?

Comment: @Subbu: Then go for Andy answer as he has not used LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "ssmmmjjkkkkrrr";
Dictionary <char, int> dictionary = new Dictionary <char, int>();

foreach(var c in str.ToLower())
    if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(c))
        dictionary.Add(c, 1);
    else
        dictionary[c]++;

foreach(var kvp in dictionary)
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + "-" + kvp.Value);
```

Or Linq;

```
string str = "ssmmmjjkkkkrrr";
Dictionary<char, int> dictionary = str
    .ToLower()
    .GroupBy(c => c)
    .ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.Count());

foreach (var kvp in dictionary)
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + "-" + kvp.Value);
```