# Using c# Dictionary to group values

Tags: c#, dictionary, char

I have a sequence of characters (eg. "}çæø     Ñ   ") and I need to obtain a **char,count** pair, where **char** is the ASCII character code and **count** is the number of consecutive repetitions of that same character.

The above sequence would thus read:

```
<125,1>
<135,1>
<145,1>
<32,5>
<155,1>
<32,3>
```

Is there a quick way of doing that with a Dictionary?

**I need to ONLY count adjacent characters (see character 32 in the above example).** I understand that Dictionaries can't have key repetitions, so is there another quick way that doesn't involve string iteration? I might have very long strings to process and iteration takes way too long.

Comment: I think that this should be possible using Linq's `GroupBy` method

Comment: Obligatory link: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: Do you really need ASCII? All those characters in your example (except the spaces and the curly brace) aren't ASCII

Comment: `string source = ...; Dictionary<char, int> result = source
   .GroupBy(c => c)
   .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());`

Comment: string input = "}çæø Ñ ";

            var results = input
                .ToCharArray()
                .Select(x => (int)x)
                .GroupBy(x => x)
                .Select(x => new { code = x.Key, count = x.Count() })
                .ToList();

Comment: Thanks @DmitryBychenko but your method groups everything. I only need to group adjacent repetitions. In my example above you can see there is a cound of 5 for blankspace (32) and then there is another count of.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count the characters individually in a string using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830228/count-the-characters-individually-in-a-string-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Did you even try **anything**? We´re not here to do your work: thinking, trying out, thinking again.

Comment: @user2729463: At least, you can't represent result as a *dictionary* since keys must be *unique* (key = 32 can't repeat)

Comment: @HimBromBeere Of course I've tried. I'm not just looking to count all characters, but ONLY adjacent characters. I'm not familiar with dictionaries, but I've noticed they're very quick and since I might be running into very long strings of characters, I can't use iteration, since it takes way too long.

Comment: I don't see, how `"}çæø Ñ "` corresponds to the expected result. Could you give some more examples? What about `"aaa"` or `"aabbaabb"` or `"banana"`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32432281/find-the-longest-repetition-character-in-string. What was the keyword you used when you search internet for an answer?

Comment: @xdtTransform Hi, tried it already. For very long strings that solution gives me an Overflow exception.

Comment: @Corak I read arbitrary character strings, but the above example could be rewritten as "abc     d   " and I need the result to look like <97,1><98,1><99,1><32,5><100,1><32,3>

Comment: @user2729463 - yes, again, I don't see, why `"abc d "` would result in `<32,5>` and `<32,3>` are there space characters missing/removed?

Comment: @Corak The character sequence is 97 98 99 32 32 32 32 32 100 32 32 32.

Comment: @user2729463 - thanks, now it makes sense.The repeated spaces don't show up in the question.

Comment: Previous linked question is your answer. With the Extention from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681949/use-linq-to-group-a-sequence-of-numbers-with-no-gaps, Totaly do the trick and the modification are easy . `var result = 
 text
 .GroupAdjacentBy((l, r) => l == r)
 .Select(x => new { letter= x.First(), count = x.Count()})
;`. The "I try it give me XYZ",  is hard to verify with the little information in your question..

Comment: @xdtTransform I'm trying it on long strings and i get an Out of Memory exception. :(

Comment: May you define long string ?

Comment: Just over a 1MB.

Comment: Still no reproduction .. https://dotnetfiddle.net/pByzCM. for 65.48Mb string it took 0.21 sec. You must be doing something wrong somewhere in your code. It may have little to do with your question.

Comment: If you are worry that the extention method is overflowing you you can modify it to return a structure with the element and the number of occurence. instead of a list. It's pretty strait forward.

Answer (score 1):

The MoreLinq library has the method you need, see [GroupAdjacent](https://morelinq.github.io/3.2/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_GroupAdjacent__3_2.htm).

Usage:

```cs
string source = "}çæø     Ñ   ";
IEnumerable<(char c, int)> groups =
    source.GroupAdjacent(x => x, (c, lst) => (c, lst.Count()));

// Outputs ('}', 1) ('ç', 1) ('æ', 1) ('ø', 1) (' ', 5) ('Ñ', 1) (' ', 3)
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", groups.Select((kv) => $"('{kv.Item1}', {kv.Item2})")));
```

Answer (score 0):

*Standard Linq* doesn't provide `GroupByAdjacent` or alike method(s), but we can implement it with a help of a simple `foreach` loop. Note, that we can't use `Dictionary<char, int>` since dictionary must have **unique** `Key`s (`Key == ' '` can't reapeat):

```
  string source = "}çæø     Ñ   ";

  // We can't use Dictionary<char, int>
  // Let's put a list instead
  List<KeyValuePair<char, int>> result = new List<KeyValuePair<char, int>>();

  foreach (char c in source)
    if (result.Count <= 0 || result[result.Count - 1].Key != c)
      result.Add(new KeyValuePair<char, int>(c, 1));
    else
      result[result.Count - 1] = 
        new KeyValuePair<char, int>(c, result[result.Count - 1].Value + 1);
```

Let's have a look:

```
  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
    .Select(pair => $"<'{pair.Key}' ({(int) pair.Key,3}) : {pair.Value}>"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:** (please, note, that `char` in *not* an Ascii character but Unicode)

```
<'}' (125) : 1>
<'ç' (231) : 1>
<'æ' (230) : 1>
<'ø' (248) : 1>
<' ' ( 32) : 5>
<'Ñ' (209) : 1>
<' ' ( 32) : 3>
```

Comment: "Note, that we can't use Dictionary<char, int>" But we can use a `LookUp`.

Comment: How would that work? I'm not familiar with Lookup's either...

Comment: In case of `LookUp<char, int>` (or, say, `Dictionary<char, int[]>`) all we have is `<' ', {5, 3}>` record: we have `5` and `3` consequent spaces *somewhere*, but we can't tell where exactly (say, "after ø symbol we have `5` spaces")